# Can I run a command in another app using C++?

Tags: c++, windows, gams-math

I'm not sure if anyone asked this, I tried to find it but I couldn't. I'm starting a new project and I want to make a GUI in C++ that will run another application called *"GAMS"* which does some optimization problems for me.

Now, I do know how to create GUI and how to run GAMS itself using `ShellExecute()`, but I don't know how to run those algorithms from my GUI.

All I need is to run scrip that I wrote in GAMS and that I would be able to manipulate with data that I receive from GAMS.

So my question is, can I send commands from my GUI to GAMS?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If you're lucky then GAMS have a library which you can link with, and call functions in the library to do what you need. Otherwise if the program uses standard input and output then you need to explicitly [create a process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) and set the input and output file handles that you can write to and read from.

Comment: If you talk about [gams.com](https://www.gams.com), then you probably should take a look on: [GAMS C++ API](https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/API_CPP_OVERVIEW.html) `[...]provides a convenient way to exchange input data and model results with in-memory representation of data (GAMSDatabase), and to create and run GAMS models (GAMSJob) that can be customized by GAMS options (GAMSOptions). Furthermore, they introduce a way to solve a sequence of closely related model instances in a more efficient way[...]` and on [Expert-Level APIs](https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/API_MAIN.html#GAMS_LLAPIS)